# Error: ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, gulp-protractor

I am trying to configure gulp to launch Protractor (and webdriver) and I get the "[launcher] Error: ReferenceError: System is not defined" . I previously set Karma to recognize System but I have no idea how to do same thing for Protractor.

Here is my protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['./dist/**/*e2e.js'],
//    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
   seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/selenium-standalone-jar/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar'
//   seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/selenium/selenium-standalone-jar/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar'
}
```

my gulp task (gulpfile.js):

```
gulp.task('e2e', function(callback) {
    gulp
        .src(['./dist/**/*e2e.js'])
        .pipe(angularProtractor({
            'configFile': 'protractor.conf.js',
            'debug': true,
            'autoStartStopServer': true
        }))
        .on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .on('end', callback);
});
```

and protractor related (package.json)

```
"gulp-protractor": "^2.1.0",
"protractor": "2.5.1",
"selenium-standalone-jar": "2.45.0",
```

Any suggestion highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040502/referenceerror-system-is-not-defined-when-using-protractor-with-angular2-and

Comment: Yes, I see ... I don't see any solution there , though ...

Comment: Does anyone have a simple working example of protractor and angular 2 .? I think I tried all the examples in git and I was able to actually run tests just the https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed which is very complicated for me. All the other example I tried I get same error.

Answer (score 2):

So, after a while I figured out what the problem was :

As I was using typescript I had imported some libraries e.g.

```
import {
    it,
    describe,
    expect
} from 'angular2/testing';
```

The ts transpiler would compile the code (as intended) adding System. ... and protractor does not know what "System" is .

*** We write code for tests is Jasmine (not angular)!

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is: NO import { ...} from 'angular2/testing' in tests , just use jasmine it, describe, etc, NO angular imports in tests .